How to quote a vertical bar | in a net use password?
I am trying to mount a network share using the net use command where the user contains a special character in the password, which is a vertical bar, or "|" character. However, I am unable to use this password in a net use command.
When I try the following:
net use o: \\myserver\myshare /user:myuser@mydomain.suffix abc|def 

I get the following error message: "d is not recognized as an internal or external command". Obviously the commandline tries to interprete that chartacter as a pipe symbol.
So I tried quoting the password using the following sytaxes, which are not working:
net use o: \\myserver\myshare /user:myuser@mydomain.suffix "abc|def" 
net use o: \\myserver\myshare /user:myuser@mydomain.suffix abc%|def 

When I try the following, the syntax is accepted, but the password afterwards is wrong:
net use o: \\myserver\myshare /user:myuser@mydomain.suffix "%abc|def%" 

"The specified network password is not correct"
However what does work is when I do not enter the password in the commandline, and enter it manually when prompted, but this cannot be automated :-(
So my simple question is: how do I have to quote this special character in my password?

^ is usually the escape character in Cmd, so ^| might work.
A plain "abc|def" should work from within PowerShell (although it seems PowerShell has its own New-SMBMapping which would be more syntax-friendly; if it did not, I would have suggested calling WNetAddConnection2W() from PowerShell anyway).
If you are automating this always on the same system – save the password in Windows Credential Manager (e.g. via cmdkey.exe or GUI). It's not any worse than having it 'saved' in a .bat file.
